# Eximstats sends Mysql table cannot repair

Tags: mysql

Mysql keeps crashing within minutes of starting. The log shows this error:

2015-10-18 12:16:02 3174 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './eximstats/sends' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed

I tried to repair eximstats with "mysqlcheck --repair eximstats" and I get this:

```
eximstats.defers                                   OK
eximstats.failures                                 OK
eximstats.sends
error    : Can't create new tempfile: './eximstats/sends.TMD'
status   : Operation failed
eximstats.smtp                                     OK
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I didn't change the tmpdir and I have 4GB of RAM which I believe is more than enough for what I need.
/var/lib/mysql/eximstats/sends.TMD is over 20MB. Is that normal?
I get this same error with eximstats/smtp.TMD now also which is over 32MB

Comment: My question was where is it writing to..not if you changed the tmpdir or not

Comment: how large is the table that you are trying to repair?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was indeed running out of RAM able to fix the issue after adding some.